# Confused about the usage of intersection operator

Tags: typescript

Consider the following type, taken from [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype).

```
type ObjectDescriptor<D, M> = {
  data?: D;
  methods?: M & ThisType<D & M>; // Type of 'this' in methods is D & M
};
```

I want to know why did the author use intersection i.e. `M & ...` in the `methods` property.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are asking about `& ThisType<D & M>` in particular, not just `&` intersection in general?

Comment: @ghybs Yes, exactly!